# How to Hide or Disable weekends in office 365 calendar

Tags: office-365, calendar

I wish to edit my 2013 Calendar and remove Saturday and Sunday from showing if possible so it only shows the work days of the week.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I don't know where to start with it.

Answer (score 3):

While logged in to your Office 365 Outlook Web Access page,  click on the settings icon next to your name and pick options.

[image: Options]

On the left hand side menu, choose "Settings", then in top breadcrumb pick "calendar"

[image]

and voila, now you can pick your calendars appearance with regards to which days you want to show up in your calendar views.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way so they don't show at all? I think thats what the question wanted.

Comment: Hi, I don't think you can remove them OOTB *as far as I know* and I haven't done much customizations for any version of Outlook, it might be possible with a simple (potentially, anyway) custom Office App you could achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    if (oTable != null) {

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
    {
    var table = oTable.item(i);
    if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
    {
    for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
    {
    if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
          }
         }
        }
       }
      } 
    });
    function month(){

    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    if (oTable != null) {

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
    {
    var table = oTable.item(i);
    if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
    {
    for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
    {
    if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    }

         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
     //For week view
     function week(){

    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    if (oTable != null) {

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
    {
    var table = oTable.item(i);
    if (table.className == "ms-acal-detail")
    {
    for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
    {
    if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    }

         }
        }
       }
      }
     }



    $( "#WPQ2_nav_prev_a" ).click(function() {
     month();
    })
    $( ".ms-picker-table" ).click(function() {
    month();
    })
    $( "#WPQ2_nav_next_a" ).click(function() {
    month();
    })
    setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
    setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
    setInterval(function () { week()}, -10000);

     </script>
```

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/121810/6382). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the prior answer but it hides the 6th and 7th day of the Week View with CSS, instead of JavaScript.  This snippet works with the Week View on the calendar webpart.  There are other class names on the Month View but it follows the same pattern.

You will also need to set the regional settings on the Site Collection to make the Week Start at *Monday*, not *Sunday*, for this code to work.  It assumes that Saturday and Sunday are the 6th and 7th days in the week.

```
   /* Week View, hide Saturday and Sunday  */
   .ms-acal-detail tbody tr td:nth-child(7), .ms-acal-detail tbody tr td:nth-child(8) {
      display:none;
   }
```

Hope this helps.